# What are the escaping rules of command arguments?

Tags: vimscript, escape, cmdline

The following does nothing:

```
:file /tmp/[some file]
```

or:

```
:file "/tmp/[some file]"
```

The following set's the file to `/tmp/[some file]`:

```
:file /tmp/\[some file]
```

What are the rules that `:file` arguments are escaped? How to pass for example a filename with newline?

Comment: "filename with newline" raargh

Answer (score 1):

> What are the rules that :file arguments are escaped?

The argument to `:file` is undergoing `expand()` function. `expand()` expands wildcards and all special keywords. All special characters `%` `#` `<`, modifiers `:p` `:h`, sequences of `<...>` and characters triggering filename expansion `*` `[` `**` `?` need to be escaped.

> How to pass for example a filename with newline?

Use the function `fnameescape()` to escape the argument.

```
execute "file ".fnameescape("/tmp/[some file]")
```

> The following does nothing:

It does nothing, because you have `set wildignore+=/tmp/*`. This causes the glob expression `/tmp/[some file]` to expand to nothing, becuase `/tmp/` is ignored, so `:file /tmp/[some file]` becomes just `:file`.